# How to make form disappear once its values are in the database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I have to create a return order form that depicts some basic information for the order like order number, payment method, address of the customer and then below the details of the order (separate products) which have a checkbox and can be clicked and after clicking on the submit button are registered in the database table that stores the returns. For that I am using php, sql queries and foreach loops to create on the same page as many forms as the orders where the option to return a product is available are.

My problem is that I cannot make those forms disappear that their order details (that is separate products) are all returned (and are registered in the equivalent table of the database). There remains on the screen the form layout of each order with the basic details I mentioned earlier and the submit buttons (I have managed though to get the checkboxes and the product details disappear each time a checked one is submitted).

Do you have any suggestions? I am using php to create the form and dynamically fill it with information. Now I just need to make the forms disappear after their listed order details are all registered as returned (if there is even one unregistered detail then the form should remain on the screen).

Comment: The first rule of code club

Answer (score 0):

PHP is great to create robust backends that interact directly with the DB. But PHP is not ideal to create intuitive UIs alone. You might want to build your UI with the help of JS and maybe use an existing framework like jQuery as a start. Your interactive parts are then realised with AJAX calls.

Comment: I have no say in the matter... I have to do it that way using php... :/